# Entity Framework average with grouping

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Trying to add averaging for the following columns: longitude and latitude

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS ID, 
    r.StateProvinceRegion, 
    AVG(s.Longitude) AS Longitude, 
    AVG(s.Latitude) AS Latitude
FROM
    RestaurantAddress r 
INNER JOIN
    Restaurant s ON s.RestaurantId = r.RestaurantId
GROUP BY
    StateProvinceRegion
```

Entity Framework code:

```
public VersionResponse GetRegions()
{
    var regionList = from restaurantAddress in _context.RestaurantAddress
                     join restaurant in _context.Restaurant on restaurantAddress.RestaurantId equals restaurant.RestaurantId
                     select new { restaurantAddress.StateProvinceRegion, 
                                  restaurant.Longitude, restaurant.Latitude, 
                                  average = (new double?[] { restaurant.Longitude, restaurant.Latitude }).Average() 
                                };

    return new VersionResponse()
               {
                    Data = regionList
               };
}
```

Currently when I try get the average of longitude and latitude, I get a http 500 error saying there was an issue with processing the LINQ expression `AsQueryable<Nullable<double>>(new Nullable<double>[]`

Is there a way I can add averaging in my query in Entity Framework?

Comment: The code is not doing grouping.

Comment: yeah I know it's not im struggling with getting the average and grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a GroupBy LINQ call in..

I generally work with/feel more comfortable with method syntax rather than query syntax so this may be a bit off:

```
select ( ... your existing query ...)
group by StateProvinceRegion into g
select new {
  StateProvinceRegion = g.Key,
  AvgLat = g.Average(x => x.Latitude),
  AvgLong = g.Average(x => xLongitude)
}
```

When you group something in LINQ you don't get a group in the SQL sense of the word; SQL takes the detail lines, groups on the key columns specified in the GROUP BY then runs the aggregates specified in the select and returns just the key and the aggregate results. LINQ stops sooner than this and keeps the detail that SQL throws away, but you have to directly process the detail to run the aggregations -
all LINQ does is divide up a list of things into a list of lists of things, so your original list of address/lat/long becomes like a `Dictionary<(address), List<(address, last, long)>>` - that is to say that for each unique address there is an associated list of all the address/lat/long that have that address.

The address is stored in g.Key and the list detail is g. This means you retrieve the address from the key, and you calculate eg the average Latitude with the typical `list.Average(element => element.Property)` pattern

Comment: What would StateProvinceRegion  be? because it's currently stored in the RestaurantAddress dto

Comment: I'm also happy to change to query syntax if that makes more sense to

Comment: Was able to work through something similar and figure it out thanks guys :)!

Comment: StateProvinceRegion would be whatever it was before; I assumed it was a string because you wrote a single column name in your SQL (so it wasn't a more complex object), and the most reasonable storage container for it seemed to be string

Comment: When you make an anonymous type with `new { FirstName = "John", LastName = x.Surname, SSN = x.SSN, x.Age }` you either give the property a name (like I did with FirstName, Lastname and SSN) or you do not (like I did with Age). If you do not supply a name, the compiler will use the name of the property you used (I didn't give Age a name, so the compiler will use Age. I gave SSN the same name as SSN, which is a waste of effort, and I should have just written x.SSN). If there is no name because you used a constant (like I did with "John") then you HAVE to give a name

Comment: how would you add a row_number as an ID in linq though? As that was part of my sql query, I've managed to get the rest of the linq working as expected

Comment: You can use the version of Select that has an indexer, but not in query syntax, so you might need to switch from query to method syntax.. You hence might need something like `(from .. where ... group ...).Select((x, index) => new { ID = index, StateProvinceRegion = g.Key ...)`

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that every Restaurant has exactly one Address, and you want the Average Location of all Restaurants per StateProvinceRegion. If your Restaurant has several Addresses, then the code won't change.

My advice would be to fetch each Restaurant with its Address, and then GroupBy StateProvinceRegion. Use the [overload of GroupBy that has a parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby).

In the resultSelector of the StateProvinceRegion you calculate the average Longitude / Lattitude.

```
var result = dbContext.Restaurant.Join(dbContext.Address,

    restaurant => restaurant.RestaurantId, // from every Restaurant take the primary key
    address => address.RestaurantId,       // from every Address take the foreign key
                                           // to the Restaurant

    (restaurant, address) => new           // when they match, use the Restaurant and 
    {                                      // the Address to make one new object
        
        StateProvinceRegion = restaurant.StateProvinceRegion,
        Longitude = address.Longitude,
        Latitude = address.Latitude,
    })

    // Result: per restaurant its StateProvinceRegion and the Longitude and Latitude
    // of the Restaurant's Address

    // from the joinResult make groups that have equal value for StateProvinceRegion
    .GroupBy(joinResult => joinResult.StateProvinceRegion,

        // parameter resultSelector: take the StateProvinceRegion
        // and all Longitudes / Latitudes that have this StateProvinceRegion
        // to make one new object:
        (stateProvinceRegion, joinResultsWithThisStateProvinceRegion) => new
        {
            StateProvinceRegion = stateProvinceRegion,

            Longitude = joinResultsWithThisStateProvinceRegion
                .Select(joinResult => joinResult.Longitude)
                .Average(),

            Latitude = joinResultsWithThisStateProvinceRegion
                .Select(joinResult => joinResult.Latitude)
                .Average(),
        });
```

Simple comme bonjour!

Comment: Thank you for the post! I don't quite understand the line whne you create a new object? StateProvinceRegion = restaurant.StateProvinceRegion how do you create StateProvinceRegion object ??

Comment: The line you are referring to, is a property in a  new object of an `anonymous type`. If you use `new` without a class name, then the anonymous type is generated, and an object of this anonymous type is created. The anonymous type is a simple class with only `{get}` properties. The line `StateProvinceRegion = ...` does not create a new object, it only assigns the value of `restaurant.State.ProvinceRegion` to the property `anonymousObject.StateProvinceRegion`. Google for `anonymous type` to see other features of this type, among others: an equality comparer that compares by value, not reference